# Read in from file into structure

Tags: c++, structure, fstream

I want to read in from txt file into structure using fstream.
I save the data to the file in the way shown below:
To read the data i tried some cheeky stuff with getlines or tabsin<

```
struct tab{
    int type,use;
    string name, brand;

};

tab tabs[500];

ofstream tabsout;
tabsout.open("tab.txt", ios::out);  
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++){
    if (tabs[i].use==1){

        tabsout << tabs[i].type << " " << tabs[i].name << " " << tabs[i].brand << "\n";

    }
}

tabsout.close();
```

//input part that fails me :(

```
    int i=0;
    ifstream tabsin;
    tabsin.open("tab.txt", ios::in);
    if (tabsin.is_open()){
    while(tabsin.eof() == false)
    {
        tabsin >> tabs[i].type>>tabs[i].name>>tabs[i].brand;
        i++
    }

    tabsin.close();
```

Comment: Can't you just do the reverse with `ifstream` and `ios::in`? You didn't even show what you have tried thus far.

Comment: I tried that and it did not work/or i did it wrong

Comment: Then maybe you should show us what you tried, tell us how it "didn't work"

Comment: I added it to the main post

Comment: The array has 500 elements but you try to save 1000?

Comment: If `name` or `brand` has spaces in it, its going to totally mess thing up parsing back in.  You should probably pick some other character as a field separator and then change your input part to use that separator.

Comment: the 500/1000 part is a mistake while putting it on the site, there will be no spaces in name or brand, if necessary it will be a _.

Comment: In case you ever do parse an entry, you might want to set `tabs[i].use=1`

Answer (score 3):

You usually want to overload `operator>>` and `operator<<` for the class/struct, and put the reading/writing code there:

```
struct tab{
    int type,use;
    string name, brand;

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, tab &t) { 
        return is >> t.type >> t.name >> t.brand;
    }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, tab const &t) { 
        return os << t.type << " " << t.name << " " << t.brand;
    }
};
```

Then you can read in a file of objects like:

```
std::ifstream tabsin("tab.txt");
std::vector<tab> tabs{std::istream_iterator<tab>(tabsin), 
                      std::istream_iterator<tab>()};
```

....and write out the objects like:

```
for (auto const &t : tabs) 
    tabsout << t << "\n";
```

Note that (like any sane C++ programmer) I've used a `vector` instead of an array, to (among other things) allow storing an arbitrary number of items, and automatically track how many are actually being stored.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, do **not** use `.eof()` to control your loop: it doesn't work. Instead, use the stream's state after reading:

```
int type;
std::string name, brand;
while (in >> type >> name >> brand) {
    tabs.push_back(tab(type, name, brand));
}
```

If your `name` or `brand` contain spaces, the above won't work and you will need to write a format where you can know when to stop abd read correspondingly, e.g., using `std::getline()`.

You might also consider wrapping the logic to read or write an object by suitable operators.

Answer (score 0):

```
istream& getline (istream&  is, string& str, char delim);
```

Take a look at the third parameter, you can use *std::getline* to parse your line. But that is definitely not the best way to serialize objects. Instead of using a text file, you should use a byte stream.