# How to create structure members inside a loop in C++

Tags: c++, loops, data-structures

I'm trying to use data structures in C++ to organize properly some data I receive from a loop.

I created my structure and the data I want to get.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
#define NumOfProducts 5

struct Product{
    int weight;
    double price;
};

int data1 [5] = { 16, 2, 80, 40, 12070};
int data2 [5] = { 8, 1, 40, 20, 6035};
```

What I want is to have 5 members of the "Product" data structure with each "weight" extracted from data1 and each "price" extracted from data2. It is just an exemple of what I want to do as my data set is a lot bigger so I think I really need a for loop and can't manually assign every case.

Here what I tried.

```
int main(void){
    Product products[NumOfProducts];
    for (int i=0; i<NumOfProducts; i++){
        products[i].weight = data1[i];
    }
    cout << products[1].weight << endl;
    cout << products << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not exactly sure of the result I get.

Do I have 5 members with 1 weight or do I have 1 member with 5 weight (as a vector) ? I'd prefer to have 5 members with 1 weight so how can I improve my loop ?

Thanks a lot

EDIT : Seems that I was confusing members and instances. This code looks better.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
#define NumOfProducts 5

struct Product{
    int weight;
    double price;
};

vector <int> data1 = { 16, 2, 80, 40, 12070};
vector <int> data2 = { 8, 1, 40, 20, 6035};

int main(void){
    Product products[NumOfProducts];
    for (int i=0; i<NumOfProducts; i++){
        products[i].weight = data1[i];
        products[i].price = data2[i];
    }
    cout << products[1].weight << endl;
    //cout << products << endl; useless as it's the location where the first element of products resides
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) "_I'm not exactly sure of the result I get._" Why you are unsure about it? It is not what you expected? In what way? 2) `cout << products << endl;` Doesn't make a lot of sense, since it will print the address where first element of `products` resides.

Comment: We don't really know either if you have 5 products with 1 weight or if you have 1 product that has 5 weights. You should create your structs to match the data that you do have.

Comment: `#include <vector>` great, now please go ahead and use it.

Comment: I think some of the confusion may come from a misunderstanding of the word "member". A `Product` has members (`weight` and `price`), but your code doesn't contain anything that has a `Product` *instance* as a member. It's very difficult to understand anything before you sort out the terminology.

Comment: You're right, I was confusing instance and members. I'm trying to create instances, not members. Also, I shouldn't include vector as I'm not using it

Comment: @A.Ben Why are you not wanting to use a vector? That's a bit like refusing to use the odd number gears in your car.

Comment: Now I'm using it, thanks. I took time to see the benefits of using vectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will explain how you can use vectors & for loops even ranged based for loops with an objects default and user defined constructor:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h> // for _getch()

const unsigned int NumProducts = 5; // Don't like #define I prefer const instead

struct Product {
    int weight;
    float price; // don't need double too much precison & memory consumption

    Product() : weight( 0 ), price( 0.0f ) {}
    Product( int weightIn, float priceIn ) :
        weight( weightIn ),
        price( priceIn ) 
    {}
};

int main() {
    // moved vectors from global; and refrained from "using namespace std" 
    // (bad practice - I prefer to use "std::" so I know what lib they are coming from.
    std::vector<int> weights{ 16, 2, 80, 40, 12070 };
    std::vector<float> prices { 8.0f, 1.0f, 40.0f, 20.0f, 6035.0f };

    // I prefer to use containers "arrays" can be messy. 
    std::vector<Product> products;
    products.reserve( NumProducts ); // 5 Products

    // If Products Are Not Already Created Use 
    // User Defined Constructor & Push Back Into Vector
    for ( unsigned i = 0; i < NumProducts; i++ ) {
        products.push_back( Product( weights[i], prices[i] ) );
    }    
    std::cout << "Output for products vector using Product( int, float ) constructor.\n";
    // To access them for printing you don't need & after the auto.
    for ( auto p : products ) {
        std::cout << "Weight = " << p.weight << ", Price = " << p.price << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // If Default Constructed Products Exist:
    std::vector<Product> products2;
    products2.reserve( NumProducts );
    Product product;
    for ( unsigned i = 0; i < NumProducts; i++ ) {
        products2.push_back( product );
    }

    unsigned i = 0; // counter needed for accessing the elements of the data vectors
    for ( auto& p : products2 ) { // Notice the & after auto; without it all values will still be 0.
        p.weight = weights[i];
        p.price = prices[i];
        i++;
    }    
    std::cout << "Output for products2 vector using Product() constructor adding data after.\n";
    // Again don't need the & after p, although it wouldn't hurt if you did use it in this case.
    for ( auto p : products2 ) {
        std::cout << "Weight = " << p.weight << ", Price = " << p.price << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I added the constructors to the Product struct for 2 main reasons:

- First: even if default constructor is used; the members will be initialized to at least 0 instead of an indeterminate value.
- Second: the user define construct allows me to create an instance of this object via constructor to easily push it back into a container.

Without the constructors and doing something like this:

```
{
    std::vector<Product> products3;
    products3.reserve( NumProducts );
    unsigned idx = 0;
    for ( auto& p : products3 ) {
        p.weight = weights[idx];
        p.price = prices[idx];
        idx++;
    }

    for ( auto& p : products3 ) {
        std::cout << p.weight << ", " << p.price << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Will not give you any results since you only reserved the memory and never added any Product instance to the container.

Comment: This seems to be what I wanted to do, in a clear and efficient way. Thanks a lot, I'll learn a lot reproducing it.

Comment: Not a problem; I don't mind helping out those new to the craft; it's a luxury that I didn't have when I first started teaching myself back in the late 90s early 2000s.

Answer (score 1):

What's your objection, given your current data, to

```
struct Product{
    int weight;
    double price;
} products[]{{16, 8}, {2, 1}, {80, 40}, {40, 20}, {12070, 6035}};
```

? If you have a large amount of data to read in from a file, say, then it's time to build a *constructor* to `Product`, and use a `std::vector<Product> products;` for the storage.

See [Read in from file into structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433370/read-in-from-file-into-structure)

Comment: @SombreroChicken: Dead simple and perfectly clear, if you understand the language. This is hardly rocket science.

Comment: And based on OP's question he's probably a beginner.

Comment: I would assume the objection is this: `It is just an exemple of what I want to do as my data set is a lot bigger so I think I really need a for loop`.

Comment: @SombreroChicken: My original comment stands. Anyone who's taken the time to read a half-decent book will understand this.

Comment: Right, I'm a beginner. With the current data, I could do what you propose but i'm trying to understand how I could automatized it

Comment: @A.Ben I've included a link to a good question on reading data into a structure. Set aside a few days to get this going.

Comment: Beginners got to start somewhere and sometimes it might even be better to get your feet wet by trial and error as opposed to reading the theory about it. Don't get me wrong there are plenty of good books out there but there are just as many bad or dangerous ones. And for someone who is a novice they probably wouldn't know what books are good or bad to develop good practices. Years back when I was teaching myself (no formal education on the matter) I did not have the luxury of books or this site, I was learning from text sites like older http & ftp ones without any interaction from others.

Comment: ...continued However; being in between intermediate and expert still purely self taught; I'm still learning and this site is a great help and resource. Sometimes I help others and sometimes others help me. I enjoy helping the newbies out because it's something I didn't have and sometimes by helping them it helps me too.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have 5 members with 1 weight or do I have 1 member with 5 weight (as a vector) ?

You have an array of 5 elements of type `Product`. All `Product` instances have a `weight` member (and also a `price` member which you have left uninitialized).

> It is just an exemple of what I want to do as my data set is a lot bigger

If the data set is much larger, then you probably can't use an automatic array. Use `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have 5 `Product` objects that each have their own seperate `weight` (and `price`) members.

The way you're initializing `weight` for each object currently is the way to go, do this for `price` too and you're set.

Do note that if you try to read any of the members before assigning them in the loop you have undefined behavior as `weight` and `height` are both uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

> What I want is to have 5 members of the "Product" data structure with
>   each "weight" extracted from data1 and each "price" extracted from
>   data2.

Then write

```
int main(void){
    Product products[NumOfProducts];
    for (int i=0; i<NumOfProducts; i++){
        products[i].weight = data1[i];
        products[i].price = data2[i];
    }
    //...
    return 0;
}
```

So the data members `weight` and `price` of each element of the array `products` are initialized with corresponding values of elements of the arrays `data1` and `data2`.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
#define NumOfProducts 5

struct Product{
    int weight;
    double price;
};

vector <int> data1 = { 16, 2, 80, 40, 12070};
vector <int> data2 = { 8, 1, 40, 20, 6035};

int main()
{
    Product products[NumOfProducts];
    for (int i=0; i<NumOfProducts; i++)
    {
        products[i].weight = data1[i];
        products[i].price = data2[i];
    }

    for (int i=0; i<NumOfProducts; i++)
    {
        cout <<"Object "<<i+1<<endl;
        cout <<"Weight = "<< products[i].weight << endl;
        cout <<"Price  = "<< products[i].price << endl;
        cout <<"\n";
    }
    //cout << products << endl; useless as it's the location where the first element of products resides
    return 0;
}

Output:
=======
Object 1
Weight = 16
Price  = 8

Object 2
Weight = 2
Price  = 1

Object 3
Weight = 80
Price  = 40

Object 4
Weight = 40
Price  = 20

Object 5
Weight = 12070
Price  = 6035
```

Whatever you are trying is correct. Above is the code that you are trying to do i think so. I just compiled and run the code. It might have solved your problem.